# Avoiding duplicate values in the datatable

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have List of Product information in Datatable1
and 
List of Already Selected Product Information in Datatable2 (which user has selected from Datatable1 and add to dattable2)
now i want to perform one check which is if user selected the from Datatable1 to add & if the same data is already exists in the List then should not get Added to List of Datatable 2
my friend suggested to use

```
 HashMap<String ,List<Model>>
```

is it better approach to achieve the functionality ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `java.util.Set` implementations rather than `List`, you could build a duplicate-free list of `Model` as follows:

```
Set<Model> dataTable1 = ...
Set<Model> dataTable2 = ...
dataTable2.addAll(dataTable1);
```

`dataTable2` will then contain everything that was either in `dataTable1` or `dataTable2`, but with no duplicates (set union operation).

Be sure to implement an appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` on the `Model` class.

Comment: Never used JSF? Until the upcoming JSF 2.2, `Set` isn't supported as `<h:dataTable value>`. So you have to convert it forth and back to/from `List` everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Rai is right in case you would like to add *one* `Product` per action, like in the view (surrounded by iterating component)

```
<h:commandButton value="Add to selected" actionListener="#{bean.addProductToList2}>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{product}" target="#{bean.selectedProduct}/>
    <f:ajax render="table2/>
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
private Product selectedProduct;

public void addProductToList2(ActionEvent event) {
    if(!list2.contains(selectedProduct)){
        list2.add(selectedProduct);
    }
}
```

Moreover, he is right regarding the choice of two lists.

If you would like to add the possibility of adding all selected products at once you could use the checkBoxes instead

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox valueChangeListener="#{bean.toggleProductInList2}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{product}" target="#{bean.selectedProduct}/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

with

```
private Product selectedProduct;

public void toggleProductInList2(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Boolean isChecked = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
    if(isChecked){
        list2.add(selectedProduct);
    } else {
        list2.remove(selectedProduct);
    }
}
```

This way a list will be prepared and could be shown on button click:

```
<h:commandButton value="Show selected">
    <f:ajax render="table-container"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="table-container">
    <ui:repeat...>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaination skuntsel.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you need HashMap for this; `List or Set` will do the job.

```
 List<Product> list1 = new ArrayList<Product>(); //from DataTable1
 List<Product> list2 = new ArrayList<Product>(); //from Datatable2

  Product p; //product which needs to be added to list2

      if(!list2.contains(p)){
          list2.add(p);
       } 
       //write list2 to db
```

So put product only if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: i think this is easy & nice approach .